# Ошибки компиляции при подключении Winsvc.h С++

Tags: c++, windows

При попытке подключить Winsvc.h сразу же появляется под 100+ ошибок, с чем может быть связано и как фиксить ? Была аналогичная проблема с winsock2, ее решил путем копирования рабочего проекта с уже подключенной библиотекой.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавте код и сообщение об ошибкекак текст.

Comment: попробуйте дефайн с второй строки перенести где то в район 10 (или совсем удалить).

Answer (score 0):

Добавите подключение windows.h перед подключение проблемного файла:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsvc.h>
```